# How to sort the field once you have used split in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using aggregate and split in MongoDB to tokenize a string field and it works fine. But I want to sort the field and for some reason, the sort with aggregate is not working at all.

```
db.coll.aggregate( { $project: { split: {$split: ["$FIELD_NAME", " "] } } } )
```

It gives me the following output:

```
{ "_id" : 112, "split" : [ "TOKEN", "EXCH" ] }
{ "_id" : 122, "split" : [ "TOKEN", "EXCH" ] }
{ "_id" : 332, "split" : [ "TOKN", "EXCH" ] }
{ "_id" : 444, "split" : [ "ABC", "IND", "INS" ] }
```

But when I try to sort the split field, it gives me an error.

```
db.table_a.aggregate( { $project: { split: {$split: ["$FIELD_NAME", " "] } } }, {$sort: {"split": -1}} )

2019-10-16T14:11:22.528-0500 E QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$split requires an expression that evaluates to a string as a first argument, found: int",
    "code" : 40085,
    "codeName" : "Location40085"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:534:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:618:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1062:12
```

I tried different ways to sort but it isn't working as expected. Can someone help?

Comment: what is the structure of the documents you are querying?  Can you provide a sample of 20 or so documents so we can play with the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unwind the split, sort and again group by _id, push the sorted split to an array.

```
db.coll.aggregate([ 
 { $project: { split: {$split: ["$FIELD_NAME", " "] } } }, 
 {$unwind: "$split"}, 
 {$sort: {split: -1}}, 
 {$group: {_id: "$_id", sorted_split: {$push: "$split"}}} 
])
```